Is there a way to use a different pytest.mark for examples in a pytest-bdd scenario outline?
I have a pytest-bdd scenario outline with 11 examples that run for it.
example feature file:

Given a bowl
And a serving spoon
When I add <fruit>
And the resulting fruit salad is served
Then the customer <will_or_not> enjoy it

Examples:

| fruit | will_or_not |
| apple | will        |
| banana| will        |
| kiwi  | will        |
.
.
.
| tomato| will not    |


Example Python file:
@pytest.mark.priority1
@scenario(scenario_file, 'Does the fruit go into the fruit salad?')
def test_fruit_salad():
    pass

What I want to do is mark the negative test (tomato, will not) as priority2 without making a new identical scenario outline.  Is it possible to mark examples differently from the same scenario outline?
